# Calculating Merkle root on chain

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries

I'd like to calculate a Merkle tree on chain, and then only store the root.

The tree will track all balances for an ERC20 token. How many accounts would this be feasible for? If there are 1000 balances would it be possible to iterate over all the balances to create the Merkle root? What is the maximum number of balances for which this would be possible?

I intend to do some testing myself, but was wondering if anyone has already dealt with this and knows what sort of limits I can expect to encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am a few years late, figured I should address this since I know the answer. In order to calculate the Merkle Proof size, one must know the number of elements from the lowest-level of the Merkle Tree as explained in full detail in my post found [here](https://soliditywiz.medium.com/merkle-hash-trees-explained-ea384f2af7e8).

> Let N = number of elements = 1,000 balances.

> Merkle Proof Size = log2(N) = log2(1000) **≈ 9.966**